# Changing a variable inside a while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a script that outputs a status bar for my window manager. It outputs the normal stuff like the time, date, weather, etc.

One of the strings it outputs is the number of updates for the system (Arch Linux). As the "API" where I am pulling the update number from has a max number of requests per day I had to add a delay to the updates() function (that outputs the number of updates) so that that maximum number of requests is not exceeded.

Adding this delay makes the problem start.

Somehow the updates_aur variable is not being stored in memory and cannot be accessed until the delay I implemented is removed. (MORE EXPLANATION IN CODE BELOW)

I would like for a delay to be implemented that makes the updates not being checked every iteration but one in 60.

I tried exporting the "updates_aur" and the "updates_arch" to environment variables so that they would be stored in memory but as the script creates a subshell they are not accessible for them to be updated/retrieved.

```
updates() {

    if [ "$internet" = true ]; then

    if ! updates_arch=$(checkupdates 2> /dev/null | wc -l ); then
        updates_arch=0
    fi

    if (( $counter % 60 == 0 )); then #this is done to add a delay and not saturate aur requests
        if ! updates_aur=$(yay -Qum --devel 2> /dev/null | wc -l); then
        updates_aur=0
      fi
    else
      :
    fi

    updates=$(("$updates_arch" + "$updates_aur"))

    if [ "$updates" -gt 0 ]; then
        echo " Updates: $updates"
    else
      echo " Updates: 0"
    fi

    echo $delim

    else
        :
  fi
}
```

This is then called in a while loop (the while loop also increments the counter by 1)

Full code: https://github.com/Baitinq/dwm/blob/master/scripts/dwm-status

I expected the variable of aur_updates to be updated and stored whenever the counter % 60 == 0, but the actual result is that the variable can only be accessed when the counter % 60 == 0, as if it wasn't being stored in memory and updated, but created with every while loop iteration in which the counter % 60 == 0.

Comment: `if ! updates_arch=$(checkupdates 2> /dev/null | wc -l )` does not really make much sense, since it is very unlikely that `wc -l` will return non-zero.  Perhaps you intended to see if checkupdates produces a line of output?  (that is, you are not checking the output of `wc`, you are checking its return status, which is almost certainly 0)

Comment: The code behind your link has erratic inlentation and a large number of shell programming antipatterns. Try http://shellchech.net/ for a start, though it might not pick up some or all of the problems I picked up by quick glance.

Comment: Thanks for the input, will definitely try to improve the overall quality of the script

Comment: @WilliamPursell The checkupdates command produces wc 0 if there are no updates ( and wc +1 per update) . It is an official script from pacman-contrib in the arch linux packages

Comment: This script is not checking the output of wc, so the output is irrelevant.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I think it is tho. At least it ouputs the number of updates correctly I believe.

Comment: It is not.  If checkupdates produces no output, then `wc -l` outputs 0 and (almost certainly) returns 0.  The script then stores the output in `updates_arch` and enters the block of the `if` depending on the value returned (not the value that was output).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running your functions in a subshell, for example (from the `status` function):

```
echo $(updates)
```

Their variables' (`updates_aur`) values are lost when the subshell exits. There's no reason to `echo` a function that contains an `echo` within it. Just call your function directly:

```
updates
```

This occurs in several places with other functions. It's also not necessary there.

Comment: Ty will fix that